# Irregular Shaped Colliders For Unity

Tags: unity

Is it possible to create an irregular-shaped collider?  If so, how?  Would I need to create a couple objects and group them up into one Game Object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mesh colliders and parented objects are the only real way to do things, Unity or otherwise.  Note that mesh colliders can be a lot more expensive, but are the only choice if you need fairly detailed collision handling for "irregular" objects.

Comment: Is it possible to import a shape as a collider?

Comment: You can import any arbitrary mesh and use a mesh collider.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a mesh collider (maybe for performance reasons), you can build a compound collider as described halfway down [this page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-BoxCollider.html).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 8 years later, but Unity still doesn't seem to have an inbuilt solution for irregular 3d shapes.

I ended up writing a class for irregular boxes. If 2 boxColliders collide, it checks further if the meshFilter's meshTriangles of box A intersect with meshFilter's meshTriangles of box B. It's not cheap at all, but for 12 triangles per cube it's fast enough. I use a different method when other mesh types are involved.

Heron solved quite all the problems some time ago, what a genius! [This link](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/3d_Math_functions?_ga=2.235304065.1452079033.1590537930-211778529.1542658618) also helped me a lot, check for `PlanePlaneIntersection`.

[image: Screenshot of intersecting cubes, with crossings outlined]

Comment: Why not simply use MeshColliders for this?

Comment: Thats just fine as long as you only want to detect collisions somehow. Maybe there are some problems with handling rigidbody components, to my knowledge you can only add one per transform (including children). But then I also wanted to calculate the mass, volume and barycenter wich I did by using each triangle as base of a tetrahedron. And I needed specific data for all the colliding triangles in order to solve collisions, cut meshes, you name it. Last, it´s not some unity hack, it´s solid math and geometry. It doesn´t break.